# AppStore Connect - What is ready for review state?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I made a new app and filled all info (description, build, keywords ..)

I submitted it to review and the state of my app was changed from " Prepare for Submission" to " Ready for Review"

Should I do something from my end ?
I don't have any "submit for review" button enabled .. I don't know what to do , I am stuck

Answer (score 13):

We've noticed that App Store Connect recently changed the app submission flow, even for a brand new app or just an update.

What worked for us was:

1. On your app detail's page, click on "Add for review", you'll be taken to a page with a pool of apps on "Ready for Review" state

[image: Click on added for review]

2. Check if everything seems alright, then click on "Submit to App Review" to finally submit it to Apple's review queue.

[image]

There should be another way to navigate to the page of apps waiting to be submitted to review, but I haven't tried to find it.

Comment: the problem was I wasent being taken to the page with a pool of apps on "Ready for Review" state automaticely! but now I think they fixed it

Answer (score 6):

You have to submit it manually.
In the Left side, in section 'General', there should be a section 'App Review':

[image]

Click on App Review, in the following screen select view located on the right side of your version, Here you can submit your app.

Comment: I clicked on App Review but It keeps loading forever on safari !! what worked for me was changing the browser to firefox and it worked

Answer (score 1):

There's so many Apple developers who have no clue what to do; why wouldn't Apple make this clearer?  Even an information (i) button would do the trick, instead of people having to come to forums and StackOverflow and waste time trying to figure something out which should be incredibly easy to present to them.

The solution:

1. Make a testing group by pressing the blue plus button under the header "External Testing" on the LHS of the App Store Connect page, and add your people to it (email required)

[image]

2. Add a testing group to your app version, by pressing the plus button (to the right of Status column, and under the Groups column header).

[image]

3. When you do this, you'll be taken to another page where you can write test requirements or a general message about your Test Flight app to your testers (What's New? etc...).  This is where you "submit for review" your app, so that a human (?) can review your app and make sure it's ok for testing.
4. Observe that when you click back to Builds iOS (upper left) you see status change to "waiting for review" (yellow clock) instead of "Ready to Submit".

[image]

Also note that your "invites" count should go up based on which groups you invited, so the invites seem to be sent even before the review is completed-- that's a nice touch Apple.
5. Wait.  in < 24 hours (typically), you'll switch to a green icon under Status.  Not sure what this does, other than prevents your test app from being removed maybe?  After it turns green, this is when you'll be given the option to submit your Test Flight app to the main app store, but this is done by clicking on "App Store" menu to the right of your App Name, and then under "iOS App" on the LHS you should see something like "1.0 Prepare for Submission" and that's how you enter the big leagues, and should expect a more thorough review.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a frustrating situation where I had my app rejected. I uploaded a new build to App Store Connect, selected it as under the Build section and clicked Save. The status changed to 'Ready for Review' but the 'Submit to App Review' button never appeared! Clicking on the 'App Review' menu item on the left pane also did not load that page.

Finally I had to dig up the rejection email, click of that 'App Review page' link to go to that page to resubmit the build.

[image]